# python selenium not open new instance window and not working

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

[image]

in many cases, my python selenium script works fine. but there is some users having problem instead script open new chrome window as usual, it open new tab in existing chrome and open url data; then the script just not working.

I still cannot found which setting makes chrome works with this kind of strange behavior.

I use this usual code

```
if sys.platform == "win32":
    chromedriverloc = folderloc+"chromedriver.exe"
else:
    chromedriverloc = folderloc+"chromedriver"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxyserver)
options.add_argument('--window-size=1356,768')


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriverloc,chrome_options=options)
```

Do you have any idea to solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

The [list of Selenium ChromeDriver command-line arguments](http://www.assertselenium.com/java/list-of-chrome-driver-command-line-arguments/) shows a --new-window option. Taking a look into [the Chromium code's webbrowser.py](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/android_ndk/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/python2.7/webbrowser.py?type=cs&q=%22--new-window%22&g=0&l=312) shows this argument in the "Launcher Class for Google Chrome browser", so adding this argument to your list:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxyserver)
options.add_argument('--window-size=1356,768')
options.add_argument('--new-window')
```

should trigger a new window instead of letting Chrome choose to open a new tab.

Comment: chrome successfully open in new window, but script still stop and not continue
I've already uninstall chrome and remove folder in c:\Users______\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\

there is information that chrome failed to start: crashed